# How to store indeces of the respective numbers in a list in seperate array using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am using python 3.6.This program should store the value of indexes of the numbers of one array into another (index starting with 1) For Eg if array is [2,3,1] the next one should be [3,1,2].. but while implemending the list gets changed.

I tried to do with respect to values of 1st array but no use it gets changed when doing the logic.

```
n = int(input())
arr = input()   
l = list(map(int,arr.split(' ')))
arr1= l
print(l)
for i in range(0,n):
    print(l[i])
    arr1[l[i]-1]=i+1
print(arr1)
```

Answer should be [4,1,2,3] but answer is [2,1,4,3]

Comment: Hi there, are you aware that `arr1= l` won't create or copy the list but instead have `arr1` point to the same place in memory as `l`?

Comment: Also for "_Answer should be [4,1,2,3]_", what was the input here?

Comment: input is 2,3,4,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for an array of the indexes of the numbers, but your example shows the indexes +1. It would probably be cleaner to stick with zero indexing.

Nevertheless, if you're looking for a (somewhat) flexible approach, you could do something like this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [2, 3, 1]
>>> [l.index(i+1) +1 if i+1 in l else None for i in range(max(l))]
[3, 1, 2]
```

Given an array that's spread out, it will fill with `None`:

```
>>> l = [2, 3, 7, 1]
>>> [l.index(i+1) +1 if i+1 in l else None for i in range(max(l))]
[4, 1, 2, None, None, None, 3]
```

It will silently ignore dupes:

```
>>> l = [2, 2, 1, 2]
>>> [l.index(i+1) +1 if i+1 in l else None for i in range(max(l))]
[3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
x = [2, 3, 1]
ind = [x.index(e) for e in sorted(x)]
# if you want your indices to start from 1
[e+1 for e in ind]
```

Comment: `list.index` returns only the first index

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question. what will user enter in `arr = input()` and what should be the expected output(`arr1`)